# How can I remove a certificate from my app's certificate store?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, certificate-store

I've got Windows Store/Phone universal app that will have to store certificates. I have no trouble loading the certificates into the app's CertificateStore, and using them. But when it comes to deleting them I have trouble.

For example, the following code works great to find my certificate in the Windows Store environment:

```
async Task<Certificate> FindMyCert()
{
    var query = new CertificateQuery();
    query.FriendlyName = "mytestcert";
    var certificates = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(query);

    if (certificates.Count != 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return certificates[0];
}
```

Now, lets say I want to remove that certificate from the store. The only "Delete" I know about is on the CertificateStore object. So I need to fetch the certificate store and then do the delete:

```
var s = CertificateStores.GetStoreByName("MY");
if (s != null)
    s.Delete(c);
Assert.IsNull(await FindMyCert());
```

There is only one problem. If you look at the documentation for GetStoreName[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores.getstorebyname.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores.getstorebyname.aspx%20GetStoreName), however, it says that the name of the certificate store can't be "MY".

The irony is this works sometimes and other times it doesn't work. I would guess there is an accepted way to do something like remove a cert from the store. But I have not been able to figure it out.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Struggeling with the same Problem here! Any luck yet?

Comment: Sadly, no. No solution, I'm afraid. I've not taken a close look at the new universal platform to see if it is in there. At the moment this is a "feature" of my app. If you find something, please link it back here! :-)

Comment: I will enquire about this at Microsoft next week.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the delay. According to customer support, this is not possible in Windows Phone 8.1. Apparently it will be supported in Win10.

Comment: ah! Great! Thanks!! You should probably answer the question, I'll mark it.

Comment: Is there any solution yet for Windows Universal Apps?

Comment: Not that I am aware of short of uninstalling and re-installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were facing the same problem recently and opened a support ticket on that case. According to MS, this is not possible in Windows Phone 8.1, I'm sorry. It should be supported in Windows 10 though.